# CefSharp can't call custom RequestHandler

Tags: c#, browser, cefsharp

In order to edit the source code before DOM is initialized I assembled this code from few sources on the internet. Then I assigned my custom `RequestHandler` to the `browser.RequestHandler` property.

```
    public class CustomRequestHandler : RequestHandler
    {
        IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
        {
            if (request.Url.Contains("sample"))
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                dictionary.Add("change this", "to this");
                return new FindReplaceResponseFilter(dictionary);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The problem is `GetResourceResponseFilter` never gets called. I am new to CefSharp so go easy with me.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#response-filtering

Comment: @amaitland it works now, thanks I also wonder if there is a dictionary method instead of a single replacement. it works fine when I use exactly the sample code but I have to change multiple strings and couldn't figure a clean way to do that

Comment: All the examples are in the project source https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.Example/Filters you might be able to adapt one of those to your requirements. You can I believe modify a response using DevTools which might be easier,  it's now possible to directly execute DevTools commands see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3158

Comment: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/ should be available in version 83 though I haven't checked to confirm.

Comment: https://github.com/Pasupathi-Rajamanickam/chrome-response-override/blob/master/devtools/devtools.js might give you pointers

Comment: @amaitland I looked through that example but how can I access the storage from CefSharp?

Comment: Post a link to the source so I know what you are referring to

Comment: @amaitland https://github.com/Pasupathi-Rajamanickam/chrome-response-override/blob/master/devtools/devtools.js here it access to storage data to edit it but I couldn't figure out how to do that with CefSharp

Comment: I need the line number

Comment: @amaitland it is 60

Comment: There is no need to access local storage in your case. I'd suggest you try https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/Filters/ExperimentalStreamResponseFilter.cs if your file is only a few hundred KB .